# How to get pdf from html page

Tags: java, html, pdf

I need to generate pdf documents that gets a lot of data from database to fill contents of document. 
First, i decided to work with Fop, made some xsl template with xml and finally got my pdf... Which was not easy to do.

But it become necessary to fill some contents interactively.. so is there any way to built documents on html/xhtml page with editable fields and eventually generate pdf from that webpage?

Comment: Take a look at [openhtmltopdf](https://github.com/danfickle/openhtmltopdf).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible but it will involve a reasonable amount of development.

There are lots of Java technologies available for developing small web apps, such as the Spring Boot Framework (https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/).

You probably want to look at PDFBox (https://pdfbox.apache.org/) for creating the PDF file.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an external API for generating PDF documents for HTML? I'm involved with a project called [pdfapi.io](https://pdfapi.io). With it, you can create PDF documents from styled HTML easily.

It has a simple API but, to make it easier we will release Java sdk soon.

Reasonable amount of requests are free of charge.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've had really good luck doing this with the Java Library called "Flying Saucer" I guess you'll need to google it because linking is not allowed here...